# How to draw half an ellipse in Raphael JS?

Tags: raphael, ellipse

I've been trying to understand the following code, but I don't seem to gain control over what the parameters are doing. I have to draw half an ellipse at a certain location. Could anyone explain to me what the parameters of the path mean in order to master this shape. Thanks.

```
var curve4 = paper.path("M150,150 A100,70 0 1,1 150,10")
            .attr({"stroke-width": 2, stroke: "red"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the syntax:

```
paper.path("M x_start,y_start A width,height rotation 1,direction x_end,y_end")
```

About that 1 between rotation and direction I'm not sure. It's probably also involved in the direction bit. I created a fiddle to play around with the ellipse parameters: https://jsfiddle.net/ansjovis/vgw3vdc8/4/